Repeated measure (2 situations) with skewed data and a covariate
I made repeated measure of all participants in 2 situations (situation A and B) for devaluing comments (devComnts) as outcome (measured as proportion: devaluing comments / all comments). Distributions in both situations are very skewed (a lot of participants made no devaluing comment at all). A paired t-test revealed that devaluing comments are lower in sitaution B. No I want to check if a covariate (myCov) may explain individual differences in devaluing comments between situations.
Due to the skewed distributions, my first approach was building difference scores of the outcome, i.e. devComntsDelta = devComnts@B – devComnts@A, which resulted in an approximately normally distributed difference score. Then I did a regression like model 'devComntsDelta ~ myCov'. From the regression results, I can see, that myCov is predicting the difference (high myCov is associated with lower difference scores), but unfortunately, I can't infere, how the difference is unfolding; so, for example, a lower difference score in participants with higher levels of myCov (as opposed to participants with lower levels of myCov) can result in several ways: having a higher "baseline" outcome score in situation A, having a lower score in situation B, or a mixture of both.
To determine, where the "change happens", I could do some tests by controlling the situation like 'devComntsDelta ~ myCov + devComnts@A' and complementary 'devComntsDelta ~ myCov + devComnts@B', but this seems pretty hackish.
I was wondering if there is another approach, like robust ANCOVA? Since I'm using R, concrete suggestions for packages/approaches are very welcome.
